# need to generate a MYSQL view with a unique column as UUID specificly as Binary16

Tags: sql, mysql, uuid

I need to generate a view which contains a column with a unique column as binary16, all I get is a varBinary16 which is not what I need.

What I tried, also using AI:

this
`CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')) AS uuid_column_name;`

does not work, also

`CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT CAST(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()) AS BINARY(16)) AS uuid_column_name;`

does not work, also this
`CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()) AS uuid_column_name;`

does not work, is there any other way to generate a MySQL view table which contains a unique column with UUID as binary16 but not varbinary16
All the above used queries either give me a varchar16 or varBinary16
I am aware that varbinary16 and binary16 are equivalent in MySQL, but I specifically need binary16

Comment: just CAST it to binary16 then?

Comment: I already tried as you can see in the second attempt CAST(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()) AS BINARY(16))